# Parent component's computed property not reactive to store state change induced from child component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

My parent component has a computed property named `showMainBanner` that contains a store state:

```
computed: {
  showMainBanner () {
    return this.$store.state.config.showMainBanner
  }
}
```

My child component, upon some user click, changes this store state thus:

```
this.$store.commit('config/SET_BANNER_STATUS', 'false')
```

... Which points to this portion of the store:

```
export const state = () => ({
  showMainBanner: true,
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_BANNER_STATUS (state, config) {
    state.showMainBanner = config
  }
}
```

The store state change is successful, yet my parent component's computed property `showMainBanner` does not react to that store change.

Why not?

Comment: how do you know it does not change?

Comment: Good question. Because in my parent component I have `<div :class="[{ 'banner-visible' : showMainBanner }, 'view view-index']">` and the `banner-visible` class is always there, meaning that `showMainBanner` never becomes `false`

Comment: Looks like this.$store.commit('config/SET_BANNER_STATUS', 'false')  dealing with 'false' as string is parsed as true by javascript

Comment: YES, thanks! I'll accept your answer if you want to make one

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
this.$store.commit('config/SET_BANNER_STATUS', 'false')
```

To:

```
this.$store.commit('config/SET_BANNER_STATUS', false)
```